# Convert 2 dataframe columns into 1 series

Tags: python, pandas

How do you take 2 columns from a dataframe and create a series (1 column as index)?

```
number  a
one     1
two     2
three   3
```

if the above was a dataframe, how would I convert it to a series with number column being the index?

I tried:

```
pd.Series(df['a'], index = df.number)
```

but all the values become nan.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? It's rather hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and select column `a`:

```
s = df.set_index('number')['a']
```

And for your solution is necessary add [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for numpy array for avoid alignment:

```
s = pd.Series(df['a'].values, index = df.number)
```